# try to encode but there is something wrong

Tags: java, arrays, encoding

I'm trying to encode a user input by converting it to a char array and then encoding it and converting it again to string to print it out but there is something wrong (it's suppose to convert A TO Z , B to Y and etc...) and ( a to z , b to y) , help i have been stuck for hours.

```js
import java.util.*;
public class PartA {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    PartA one = new PartA();
    String i = one.encode();
    System.out.println(i);
  }

  public String encode() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = input.nextLine();
    char ch[] = word.toCharArray();
    for (int x = 0; x <= ch.length; x++) {

      if (ch[x] >= 'A' || ch[x] >= 'z') {
        ch[x] = (char)(ch[x] + 25);
      }
    }
    String enc = ch.toString();
    return enc;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as javascript?  Am I just tired and missing something?

Comment: You don't say what's wrong, but at least part of it is `ch[x] = (char)(ch[x] + 25);` Work through that by hand and figure out what it's doing. For example, if `ch[x]` is `'D'`, what's that going to result in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about the logic to do this conversion.

The first step is study the [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) and find the logic behind what you need.

For example, if you need to convert `A` in `Z`, `B` in `Y` and etc, find the correlation:

```
A - Z
65 - 90

B - Y
66 - 89

C - X
67 - 88

...
```

The same for `a` to `z`, `b` to `y`...

This code can resolve your problem:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PartA {

    private final static int A_UPPER_ASCII_NUMBER = 65;
    private final static int A_LOWER_ASCII_NUMBER = 97;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PartA one = new PartA();
        String i = one.encode();
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public String encode() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = input.nextLine();
        char ch[] = word.toCharArray();
        for (int x = 0; x < ch.length; x++) {

            if (ch[x] >= 'A' && ch[x] <= 'Z') {
                int res = (25 + (A_UPPER_ASCII_NUMBER - ch[x]) * 2);
                ch[x] = (char) (ch[x] + res);
            }

            if (ch[x] >= 'a' && ch[x] <= 'z') {
                int res = (25 + (A_LOWER_ASCII_NUMBER - ch[x]) * 2);
                ch[x] = (char) (ch[x] + res);
            }
        }
        String enc = ch[0] + "";
        return enc;
    }
}
```

There is a better logic to the same thing, of course.

Comment: Thank you for explaining

Answer (score 0):

Adding 25 to a char will not do what you think.

Consider the char 'B'. It has Ascii value 66, adding 25 will give 91 which is a '['.

See [here](http://www.asciitable.com) for a list of chars and their corresponding Ascii values.

Think about what you want to achieve. You want 'B' to map to 'Y', ie you want the second char to map to the second to last char. The third char to map to the third to last char. How can you achieve that?

Comment: another for loop ? or adding a counter and assigning it to a number and doing counter-- ?